# Visual C++ double vs C++ double

Tags: c++, visual-c++, types, double

I have ported some code from C++ to Visual C++ (this is the first time I have coded in the Visual C++ environment). The code is doing a lot of math and I can see that the original code and the ported code have different results.

Almost all my variables are of datatype double.

Maybe it's a dumb question, but is there any difference between a Visual C++ double and a C++ double? Any range differences? I can't seem to find any Visual C++ documentation explaining its datatypes.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? And for what compiler was the code originaly written for?

Comment: What is a C++ double supposed to be?

Comment: Also, are you seeing differences in *optimized* builds? Compiler options can affect floating point math.

Comment: Are they not the same as in totally wrong or not the same as in verrrry slight different values

Comment: "I have ported some code from C++ to Visual C++" This doesn't mean anything. C++ is a programming language, Visual C++ is an environment for programming in that language.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2010 professional edition. The code is originally written in Embarcadero 10 years ago - not by me so i dont know much about it. Some values are actually very close but some are also very far away. @Sebastian Redl: Thanks now i know that :) as i said i have never programmed in Visual C++(environment)

Answer (score 4):

Visual C++ stores doubles using the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) format. There's no specific definition for a "C++ double", but I'd be amazed if you could find out that wasn't using IEEE 754 as it's the native encoding for most CPUs.

So no, there isn't a difference!

Comment: There should be no difference :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/03/22/intermediate-floating-point-precision/

VS has a **/fp** option (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) to specify the floating point precision (similar to fastmath for CUDA). Some of these can also prevent intrinsics; if you have conversions it may be a lot of difference..

Finally, behavior and defaults for these settings are compiler-dependent (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ebab293c-0c85-462e-a352-22ff8ee55c36/sqrt-code-optimization-is-twice-faster-on-vs20082010-than-vs2012-sse?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: Thx for the links, it explains a few things. I'll use some of the suggestions and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at first sight, but different compilers may optimize expressions differently.

Code generation options in a project properties have a floating point model setting. It can be precise, strict or fast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It set to Precise. When i change it to Strict i get the following error: D8016: '/clr' and '/fp:strict' command-line options are incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand in 32-bit mode Visual Studio uses x87 and in 64-bit mode it uses at least SSE2.  The default for Visual Studio is to compile in 32-bit mode even on a 64-bit OS whereas the default for compiling on GCC is to use 64-bit mode on a 64-bit OS.  So perhaps it's just a question of 32-bit or 64-bit mode.  Try compiling your code in 64-bit mode in Visual Studio.  You can do that even in the Express version since MSVC 2010.

x87 and SSE are different hardware.  x87 uses 80-bits for internal calculations (but only stores 64-bits) and SSE only has 64-bits.  Wikipedia has a good explanation of why 80-bits were chosen for x87 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#Need_for_the_80-bit_format